# is there a speed difference using CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css, performance, css-selectors, comparison

**HTML**

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
   <div class="c3">
    <span class="text">Text</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, i want to change *color* of `span` with class `text`,if indeed my case is as easy as above, which **CSS** selector is faster when running the *browser* ?

1. using the **element name** of *his parents* - complex : `div > div > div > .text`
2. using the **class name** of *his parents* - complex : `.c1 > .c2 > .c3 > .text`
3. using the **class name** of *his parent - only one level above target* : `.c3 > .text`
4. using the **element name** and **class name** of the *target* : `span.text`
5. just use **class name** of the *target* : `.text`
6. other (if you have other choices)

Maybe my question isn't too important for you, but the answer to this question will be very useful in structuring my CSS file

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't matter

Comment: according to [this](https://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) the fastest way would be to just use the class name of the target (`.text`).

Comment: actually browser handle all this very efficently so both are almost equivalent, you don't see big difference, you probably won't see any difference

Comment: as @TemaniAfif said you don't see big difference but for heavy web pages, it it better to have a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/)

Comment: using excessive parent selectors is inefficient [according to this](https://jordankasper.com/css-selector-efficiency-and-why-i-only-mildly-care/).  If you want to test your selector speed, you can try using this project: https://github.com/benfrain/css-performance-tests.  This is a recent speed  test for certain selectors: https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/ but as it shows, it's not really an issue with todays browsers unless you have a massive page